# Обращение к определенному контексту при запуске стороннего кода в консоли

Tags: javascript, context

Моя цель обратиться к определенному полю на сайте, используя при этом сторонний JS-код.
Проблема в том что это поле находится в отдельном iframe и обратиться к нему нельзя. Однако если в панели разработчика в браузере (Chrome), поменять context то обращение к полю работает.
Мой вопрос заключается как обратиться к этому полю из консоли с помощью JS. 
[image: изменение контекста в консоле]

Answer (score 0):

Не ждите, что можно просто сделать запись или чтение с глобальным объектом другого контекста: подразумевается, что они работают в разных потоках. Судя по [документации](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), расширения в chrome общаются с веб-страницей через window.postMessage()

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Frame</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button>Send message</button>
    <script>
      (function() {

        const ACTION = {
          SHOW_ALL: 'SHOW_ALL',
          SHOW_COMPLETED: 'SHOW_COMPLETED',
          SHOW_ACTIVE: 'SHOW_ACTIVE'
        }

        const handler = ({origin, data}) => {
          if (origin !== url) {
            return;
          }
          switch (data) {
            case ACTION.SHOW_ALL:
              alert('Show all');
              break;
            case ACTION.SHOW_COMPLETED:
              alert('Completed');
              break;
            case ACTION.SHOW_ACTIVE:
              alert('Show active');
              break;
            default:
              throw new Error(`Invalid action ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
          }
        }

        const { protocol, host, hash, href } = location;
        const url = `${protocol}//${host}`;
        const target = hash === "#child" ? opener : open(location.href + "#child");
        window.addEventListener('message', (e) => handler(e));
        document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => 
          target.postMessage(ACTION.SHOW_ALL)
        );
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Основательно продумайте архитектуру. Передаваемые объекты должны наследовать интерфейс [Transferable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Transferable) либо быть простыми (строки, числа, массивы, объекты без функций). Обычно, для взаимодействия применяют The State Reducer Pattern.

> The Transferable interface represents an object that can be transfered between different execution contexts, like the main thread and Web workers. This is an abstract interface and there is no object of this type.

Для запуска этого примера вам потребуется веб-сервер. Вы можете использовать встроенный в третий питон запустив команду `python3 -m http.server`, если он установлен. Пример показывает как можно организовать структурированное общение между двумя вкладками, взаимодействие с другими контекстами реализуется тем же способом.